# On the Origin of Homo Sapiens

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, origins

Paleoanthropologists are certain Homo sapiens originate from Africa. However where in Africa is still contested.
Could you give the reasons why it is thought that Homo sapiens evolved in Eastern Africa, Northern Africa and Southern Africa?

Comment: This seems like a question that could use some preliminary research. For example, why are paleoanthropologists "certain Homo sapiens originate from Africa"? Do those techniques extend to subregions of Africa?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? And please take the trouble to read the [Tour] to find out how this site works and how to ask questions here. Armand’s remark reflects the requirement to demonstrate the effort you have made to answer a question yourself.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that the oldest and most primitive proto-human signs of life have been found in Africa. The seminal research was done by [Louis Leakey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Leakey), an anthropologist. It is possible that older forms of life may exist undiscovered in other places, but so far the evidence for that is scant.

Part of the challenge is that many geographic areas feature acidic soils which will eventually dissolve bones, which are composed of calcium carbonate, so it requires a neutral or slightly basic soil to preserve bones over millions of years.